Deploy Streamlit app into github server, bokeh function get_svg() has error
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io.export import get_svgs

fig = figure(title=f'{file.name}', x_axis_label='Time(s)', y_axis_label='Amplitude', width=800, height=400, y_range=(-40, 40))
fig_data = get_svgs(fig)
fig_data = fig_data[0]
fig_data = fig_data.encode('utf-8')

I deploy my streamlit app into github server, using bokeh module to plot graph. I want to save the figure using get_svg(). Here I get the error traceback:
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 600, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/read_plist/read_plist_web.py", line 439, in <module>
    fig_data = get_svgs(fig)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bokeh/io/export.py", line 273, in get_svgs
    web_driver = driver if driver is not None else webdriver_control.get()
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bokeh/io/webdriver.py", line 153, in get
    self.current = self.create()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bokeh/io/webdriver.py", line 157, in create
    driver = self._create(kind)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bokeh/io/webdriver.py", line 175, in _create
    raise RuntimeError("Neither firefox and geckodriver nor a variant of chromium browser and " \

How to solve this?

Reference links:
https://docs.streamlit.io/deploy/streamlit-community-cloud/deploy-your-app/app-dependencies
You can add packages.txt into your workspace to make your serve to install the componets to debug this error.
packages.txt:
build-essential
pkg-config
default-libmysqlclient-dev
chromium-driver

